# Regular expression for Google Analytics funnel step

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am having some issues trying to pull together a regular expression for a Google Analytics funnel step.

This is what I have so far:

^/SpecificTextString/.*/**AnyTextStringWithExclusions**

The bit I am struggling with is **AnyTextStringWithExclusions**. This should match any text string with the exception of the following:

- Web_phonecall
- phonecall

All suggestions will be gratefully received!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^/SpecificTextString/.*/(?!Web_phonecall|phonecall)([a-zA-z]+)$
```

Here's a demo on regexr: http://regexr.com/38orq

(The expression on regexr.com is slightly different because regexr forces you to escape forward slashes)